# Common way to let users add iframes to their profiles?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my webapp,  I want to let users add these types of content to their profiles:

Soundcloud widgets,
youtube videos,
other similar iframes

I've heard lettings users add html type content can be dangerous.

Which measures should i take so that im on the safe side?

My app stack:

Node.js - express.js - pug - mongodb

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get only the URL/SRC from the user. For example,

**User Input :** https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyzzz

**Express :**

```
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {

    ...

    console.log(youtube); // https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyzzz
    res.render("profile", { video: youtube });
})
```

**View (Pug) :**

```
iframe(width='420', height='315', src=video)
```

**Render (HTML) :**

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyzzz"></iframe>
```

Comment: what about soundcloud? they only have the url, and the iframe code. I tried adding the url to the src, and it refuses to connect.